# emacs Terminal control-esc-% ("query-replace-regex") ignore the "control" and yields plain meta-% (query-replace)

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings, macos-monterey

macOS Monterey 12.2.1.  Using the built-in emacs from Terminal, I often want to do query-replace-regexp.  According to GNU docs, the shortcut is C-M %, so I type control-Esc %.  But emacs doesn't notice the control key.  Instead it gives me the non-regex query-replace, as if I had just typed Esc % (M %).

When I type control-Esc, the command buffer at the bottom of the emacs window shows just ESC, whereas I had expected to see something like C-ESC.

For other commands, like C-r for search, C-( to learn a macro, etc the control key works just fine.

Has anybody seen this behaviour, or could suggest how I can make C-M % work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Mac, but you're probably running into a similar situation: terminal applications depend on your terminal emulator sending the adequate escape sequences for keys with modifiers. Frequently, they will not differentiate between M- and C-M-, so there's nothing Emacs can do on its side. The same happens with me on Linux, on the Tilix terminal emulator.

Unless you have some really specific needs, I'd recommend running emacs in GUI mode. Here's a [really opinionated article](https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2016/12/29/don-t-use-terminal-emacs.html) about GUI vs terminal emacs.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead to bring a lot of features I don't need (displaying images, rich text, editing remote files) just to get one particular command working.  Maybe there's a way I could bind some other keystroke shortcut to query-replace-regexp?

Comment: Oh, you can definitely do that. For example, you can do `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-%") 'query-replace-regexp)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a `query-replace-regexp` on the terminal *by first starting a regexp `isearch-forward-regexp`* (`backward` works too), there are two ways to do this:

1. Start an isearch with `C-s` or `C-r`, followed by `M-r` to switch to a regular expression
2. `C-M-s` or `C-M-r` to start a regexp isearch directly.

If you then hit `M-%`, it'll start a query replace using your active isearch term (which was a regular expression) as the "replace" value.

2. Hit `M-r` to switch to regular expression and enter your regular expression to be replaced
3. Hit `M-%` to start a replace

Hitting `M-%` from an active isearch uses your search term as the replace term, and it matches the current mode.

Per [Chris Johnson's answer](https://superuser.com/a/83419/148887), the reason you can't type `C-M-%` on the terminal is [because `C-%` is not part of the standard control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).